# ¿Cuál es la complejidad algorítmica de este algoritmo?

Tags: complejidad, notacion-o

Necesito saber la complejidad `O(f)` de este algoritmo que consiste en un ciclo doble.

Según he estudiado, su complejidad debería ser `O(n^2)` debido a que se están anidando bucles, el problema es que el bucle más externo tiene como límite un número explícito, por lo que su complejidad debería ir a `O(n)`.

Quisiera saber si mi deducción es correcta o la complejidad es otra. Gracias.

```
Entero i, n, x, k, Sum;
Real Prod;
Prod = 1;

Para i = n hasta 1 en -1 hacer
   Sum = 0;
      Para k = i hasta n en 1 hacer
         Sum = Sum + (i*k – n*x)^2;
      FPara;
         Prod = Prod * ( (n/x) + Sum );
FPara;
```

Answer (score 1):

En el ciclo exterior, el límite no es un número explícito, sólo estás decrementando desde un valor `N` hasta 1. Decrementas por un valor constante a partir de un valor que cambia dependiendo de `N` hasta llegar a 1 y eso siempre es `O(n)` (lo ejecutas N veces, ¿no?).

Así pues, la cantidad de veces que el ciclo interior se ejecuta nos da la pista y el par de ciclos anidados efectivamente es `O(n^2)`. Te queda decidir si lo que está dentro de los ciclos anidados es `O(1)`; también te queda revisar qué pasa con `Prod = Prod * ( (n/x) + Sum );` (acostúmbrate a indentar el código correctamente para que no pierdas de vista cosas)

Comment: Gracias. Y sí, efectivamente después de analizarlo mejor concluí que era O(n**2).